# response time in Loadrunner and in VSTS 2010

Tags: loadrunner

I have tested a web application written in java using Loadrunner and vsts 2010 ultimate.I can see that the response time of each component in a page is higher that thsoe found in VSTS. Please find below the sample components for your reference;

URL LoadRunner  VSTS 2010
https://library/    0.54    0.34
https://library/main.asp        0.24

Please help me in getting  this out to my mail "mahi_ella@yahoo.co.in"

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with VSTS but I can think of a situation where LoadRunner also fetches the RESOURCES of the page, whereas VSTS only retrieves the HTML page.

If this is the case then LR will automatically take longer since it makes more requests and downloads much more data.